# Chartjs last label not shown

Tags: javascript, graph, chart.js

[UPDATE] The question seems to be solved (see comments). I will update the answer as soon as i am sure about it

I am trying to achieve a weather chart using **chartjs** library.
The chart will always have the weather date of the first day of the month and in addition to that one value in between (makes 24 values).
I want all "first day of the month" labels to be shown (with the corresponding gridline), the other data point in between should not be shown (or at least with no gridline).
The Problem now, somehow the last (12th) label is not gonna be shown and I have no idea why. The result looks like that:

[image: graph]

My javascript code is that

```
 var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: [
            "01","","02","","03","","04", "","05","","06","","07","","08","","09","","10","","11", "","12",""
        ],
        datasets: [{
          label: 'Temperature [°C]',
          data: [
              1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6
          ],
          borderColor: "rgb(0, 182, 206)",
            pointRadius: 1,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 182, 206,0.4)"
        }]
      },
      options: {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            legend:{
                display:false   // Suppress interactive legend
            },
            scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                      scaleLabel: {
                        display: false,
                        labelString: 'Month'
                      } ,
                    afterTickToLabelConversion: function(data){
                            var xLabels = data.ticks;
                            xLabels.forEach(function (labels, i) {
                                if (xLabels[i].length == 0){
                                    xLabels[i] = '';
                                }
                            });
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            //maxRotation: 0,
                            //minRotation: 0,
                            autoSkip: true,
                            maxTicksLimit: 12
                        }
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                      scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Temperature [°C]'
                      },
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]

            }
        }

    });
```

Do you have some ideas?

Comment: Can you try adding `suggestedMin: 0,` before your `beginAtZero:true` statement and see if it is working?

Comment: @DavidR unfortunatly it's not working. Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: @ThomasRichter not sure whats wrong with your code but it works here http://jsfiddle.net/uLUAT/1138/ can u share your css or a working fiddle

Comment: Can you please look at my fiddle is that what you want http://jsfiddle.net/adishri22/5vopmdm8/

Comment: @DavidR I have found the issue, thanks to you! You are using Version 2.1 (?) of the chartjs libary, whereas i was using version 2.1.4. .
It seems to be a bug in my libary, with your libary version it seems to work yes.
Thanks you very much!
I assume i am going to contact the developers to report the issue.

Comment: Glad that it is worked!. :-)